How do I configure Apps Script time-based Triggers to execute successfully?
I have implemented 2 Triggers in Apps script. The goal of these triggers are to execute only on 15th and last day of each month. Current issue, triggers are attempting to execute multiple times daily which is causing error exception: This script has too many triggers. Triggers must be deleted from the script before more can be added.
Trigger 1 (copyDatabase):
Expected results: Trigger copies a specified range from Source sheet (Index) to Destination sheet (All Work Orders) on the 15th of each month and last day of each month (between 11pm to midnight)
/// TRigger

ScriptApp.newTrigger("copyDatabase")
   .timeBased()
   .atHour(23)
   .everyDays(1) 
   .create();

function copyDatabase() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Index");
  var desinationsheet = ss.getSheetByName("All Work Orders");

  var startRow = 2; 
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - startRow + 1; 
  var startCol = 23;
  var numCols = 14;
  var startColTarget = 1;
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, startCol, numRows, numCols); 
  var data = dataRange.getValues(); 
  var Copy = "Copy"; 
  var firstEmptyRow = sheet.getRange("A2:P").getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow() + 1;
  var dataToCopy = data.filter(row => row[2] !== Copy);

  desinationsheet.getRange(firstEmptyRow, startColTarget, dataToCopy.length, dataToCopy[0].length).setValues(dataToCopy);
}

Trigger 2 (exportTriggerFunction):
Expected results: Trigger executes function and exports to specified sheet/tabs to Excel on the 15th (between 11pm to midnight) and last day of each month (between 11pm to midnight)
///////////////
/// TRigger

ScriptApp.newTrigger("exportTriggerFunction")
   .timeBased()
   .atHour(23)
   .everyDays(1) 
   .create();

function exportTriggerFunction()
{
  var today = new Date();
  var lastDayOfMonth = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth()+1, 0);

  if(today.getDate() == lastDayOfMonth.getDate() )
  {
var exportSheetIds = 
  ["560568812","1440952465","439649389","513481136",
   "1088500659","133657514","1618608630","802444630",
   "1834450484","657423004","682313931","1980296394","635144452"]; // Please set the sheet IDs you want to export.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var name = sheet.getRange('Reference!M2').getDisplayValue();
  var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("1HRchNqQ5_0LYzfULw1hWN_ALNuijsy2q"); // Google Drive Folder Location

  // 1. Copy the active Spreadsheet as a tempora Spreadsheet.
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().copy('tmp');
  const sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
  const check = sheets.filter(s => exportSheetIds.includes(s.getSheetId().toString()));
  if (check.length == 0) {
    throw new Error("No export sheets.");
  }

  // 2. Convert the formulas to the texts.
  sheets.forEach(sheet => {
    if (exportSheetIds.includes(sheet.getSheetId().toString())) {
      const targetRange = sheet.getDataRange();
      targetRange.copyTo(targetRange, { contentsOnly: true });
    }
  });

  // 3. Delete/Exclude sheets: Index and Reference
  sheets.forEach(sheet => {
    if (!exportSheetIds.includes(sheet.getSheetId().toString())) {
      spreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheet);
    }
  });
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  // 4. Retrieve the blob from the export URL.
  const id = spreadsheet.getId();
  const xlsxBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=${id}&exportFormat=xlsx`, { headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}` } }).getBlob();

  // 5. Create the blob as a file.
  destination.createFile(xlsxBlob.setName(`${name}.xlsx`));

  // 6. Delete the temporate Spreadsheet.
  DriveApp.getFileById(id).setTrashed(true);

  }
}


Initially, my strategy for executing on the 15th was to configure each trigger's settings
Select type of time based trigger: Month Timer
Select day of month: 15th
And for executing on the last day of the month, I attempted to edit the code script, but this combination is currently causing the error exception.

Focus the question on one of the triggers

I believe your goal is as follows.

You have 2 functions copyDatabase and exportTriggerFunction.
Those functions work fine.
You want to execute these functions by the time-driven trigger.
In your situation, you want to execute only one time both functions copyDatabase and exportTriggerFunction from 23:00:00 to 00:00:00 on the 15th day and the last day of each month.

In this case, how about the following modification?
Modification points:

When I saw your script is your actual script, it seems that ScriptApp.newTrigger("copyDatabase")... and ScriptApp.newTrigger("exportTriggerFunction")... are used as the global. In this case, when copyDatabase and exportTriggerFunction are run, 2 time-driven triggers are installed. And, the triggers are not deleted. I guessed that your showing image might indicate it.

In order to achieve your goal, how about the following flow?

Run a script for installing the time-driven trigger.

In this case, the 15th day or the last day of this month is selected from today's date and time.


When the time-driven trigger is run, the functions copyDatabase and exportTriggerFunction are run. And, the next time-driven trigger is installed.

In this case, the 15th day or the last day of this month is selected from today's date and time.
Here, the functions copyDatabase and exportTriggerFunction are used by putting into a function like wrapFunction. From your showing script, I guessed that both functions might be able to be finished within 6 minutes.



When this flow is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.
Modified script:
Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor. And, please manually run the function installTriggers. By this, the 1st time-driven trigger is installed. After this, the functions copyDatabase and exportTriggerFunction are automatically run by automatically installed the time-driven trigger.
In this modification, only one time-driven trigger is used.
// --- I added the below script.
function installTriggers() {
  // These values are from your question.
  const time = 23;
  const dates = [15, 0];


  const extraTime = 60; // seconds
  const functionName = "wrapFunction";
  ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().forEach(t => {
    if (t.getHandlerFunction() == functionName) {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(t);
    }
  });
  const now = Date.now();
  const triggerDate = dates.map(e => {
    const d = new Date();
    d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + (e > 0 ? 0 : 1), e);
    d.setHours(time, 0, 0);
    if (d.getTime() < now + (extraTime * 1000)) {
      d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1);
    }
    return d;
  }).sort((a, b) => a.getTime() > b.getTime() ? 1 : -1)[0];
  ScriptApp.newTrigger(functionName).timeBased().at(triggerDate).create();
}

function wrapFunction() {
  installTriggers();
  copyDatabase();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  exportTriggerFunction();
}
// ---



// --- Below script is your showing script.
function copyDatabase() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Index");
  var desinationsheet = ss.getSheetByName("All Work Orders");

  var startRow = 2; 
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - startRow + 1; 
  var startCol = 23;
  var numCols = 14;
  var startColTarget = 1;
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, startCol, numRows, numCols); 
  var data = dataRange.getValues(); 
  var Copy = "Copy"; 
  var firstEmptyRow = sheet.getRange("A2:P").getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow() + 1;
  var dataToCopy = data.filter(row => row[2] !== Copy);

  desinationsheet.getRange(firstEmptyRow, startColTarget, dataToCopy.length, dataToCopy[0].length).setValues(dataToCopy);
}

function exportTriggerFunction()
{
  var today = new Date();
  var lastDayOfMonth = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth()+1, 0);

  if(today.getDate() == lastDayOfMonth.getDate() )
  {
var exportSheetIds = 
  ["560568812","1440952465","439649389","513481136",
   "1088500659","133657514","1618608630","802444630",
   "1834450484","657423004","682313931","1980296394","635144452"]; // Please set the sheet IDs you want to export.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var name = sheet.getRange('Reference!M2').getDisplayValue();
  var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("1HRchNqQ5_0LYzfULw1hWN_ALNuijsy2q"); // Google Drive Folder Location

  // 1. Copy the active Spreadsheet as a tempora Spreadsheet.
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().copy('tmp');
  const sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
  const check = sheets.filter(s => exportSheetIds.includes(s.getSheetId().toString()));
  if (check.length == 0) {
    throw new Error("No export sheets.");
  }

  // 2. Convert the formulas to the texts.
  sheets.forEach(sheet => {
    if (exportSheetIds.includes(sheet.getSheetId().toString())) {
      const targetRange = sheet.getDataRange();
      targetRange.copyTo(targetRange, { contentsOnly: true });
    }
  });

  // 3. Delete/Exclude sheets: Index and Reference
  sheets.forEach(sheet => {
    if (!exportSheetIds.includes(sheet.getSheetId().toString())) {
      spreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheet);
    }
  });
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  // 4. Retrieve the blob from the export URL.
  const id = spreadsheet.getId();
  const xlsxBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=${id}&exportFormat=xlsx`, { headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}` } }).getBlob();

  // 5. Create the blob as a file.
  destination.createFile(xlsxBlob.setName(`${name}.xlsx`));

  // 6. Delete the temporate Spreadsheet.
  DriveApp.getFileById(id).setTrashed(true);

  }
}

Note

In this modification, your ScriptApp.newTrigger("copyDatabase")... and ScriptApp.newTrigger("exportTriggerFunction")... are removed. If you don't remove them, this script cannot be correctly worked. Please be careful about this.

References:

getProjectTriggers()
deleteTrigger(trigger)
newTrigger(functionName)


thanks for your very detailed and clear guidance. After reviewing your comments, I have re-assembled the scripts and it is working as expected, very sufficiently. Also, thanks for the additional references to review.

@Jarvis Davis Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

First, if you're shooting for a trigger that runs only on the 15th and last day of each month, you're configuring it wrong.  You should be using timeBased trigger that uses onMonthDay syntax.
Second, I don't know where in your code you had it set up to programmatically add those triggers, but you've run the script so many times it's added a lot of copies. I'd clean that up.
If you don't need the triggers to be added programmatically, I'd just install them manually using onMonthDay. I'd also use 1st day of the month, midnight-1am, instead of last day of the month (because you can't set manually it to the last day of the month directly, just a number).
